# How to override admin save_model method

Tags: python, django

I use slugify to create slugs for my blog's posts urls. In order to accept in the slug also non english characters (greek), I overrode Post model's save() method, with one that includes a parameter `allow_unicode=True`. However that couldn't work in admin area. Whenever I tried to set a greek characters slug in admin area either by setting a new post with greek title, or by editing the english slug of an existing post, admin form wouldn't allow me to save. For that, as I found in other threads, I should override the save_model() method in admin.py file. So I did, but I get an error. Now the error I get points out that admin area requested the post whose slug is going to change with the old url (an id based one), instead of the slug-url I set in the urls.py.

The error I get is either an `AttribureError at /admin/blog/post/1` (when I'm editing the slug of an existing post), or an `AttribureError at /admin/blog/post/add` (when I'm adding a new post). And the exception value in both cases is `'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'save'`

How should I set admin-side save methods to request the urls using slug urls?
Thank you in advance!

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from django.utils.text import slugify
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=100)
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title, allow_unicode=True)
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**admin.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post
from django.utils.text import slugify

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}
    list_display = ('title', 'slug', 'is_published', 'author', 'date_posted')
    list_editable = ('is_published',)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not obj.slug:
            obj.slug = slugify(obj.title, allow_unicode=True)
        super(PostAdmin, self).save_model(self, request, obj, form)

admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path, register_converter, re_path
from .views import (
    PostListView,
    UserPostListView,
    PostDetailView,
    PostCreateView,
    PostUpdateView,
    PostDeleteView,
    TagIndexView
)
from django.urls.converters import SlugConverter

class CustomSlugConverter(SlugConverter): 
    regex = '[-\w]+'

register_converter(CustomSlugConverter, 'custom_slug')

urlpatterns = [
    path('front_page', PostListView.as_view(), name='blog-home'),
    path('user/<str:username>', UserPostListView.as_view(), name='user-posts'),
    re_path(r'post/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    re_path(r'post/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/update$', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
    re_path(r'post/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/delete$', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),
    path('tag/<slug>', TagIndexView.as_view(), name='tag-posts'),
]
```

EDIT: Here is the error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/george/PythProj/myWebsite/myws_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/george/PythProj/myWebsite/myws_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/george/PythProj/myWebsite/myws_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 614, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/george/PythProj/myWebsite/myws_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/george/PythProj/myWebsite/myws_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/george/PythProj/myWebsite/myws_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 233, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/george/PythProj/myWebsite/myws_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1656, in change_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/home/george/PythProj/myWebsite/myws_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/george/PythProj/myWebsite/myws_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/george/PythProj/myWebsite/myws_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1534, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/home/george/PythProj/myWebsite/myws_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1580, in _changeform_view
    self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)
  File "/home/george/PythProj/myWebsite/blog/admin.py", line 15, in save_model
    super(PostAdmin, self).save_model(self, request, obj, form)
  File "/home/george/PythProj/myWebsite/myws_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1093, in save_model
    obj.save()

Exception Type: AttributeError at /admin/blog/post/1/change/
Exception Value: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'save'
```

EDIT2: The solution to avoid the error was of course to write my super() method in a correct way. However that didn't give to my code the functionality I wanted. So what seems to be the solution to my problem, is to declare the slug in my model as a CharField, instead of SlugField. In that case I can even remove my save_model() method that was the reason for the post. Now I'm checking if is going to be any side effect of removing the SlugField. If not I should find the thread I saw that solution to give the credit, if there are side effects I should restore SlugField and find a way to override its `validate_slug` class. That's all, thank you guys for your response!

EDIT3: Hadn't notice that `allow_unicode=True` could be argument not only for `slugify()`, but also for `models.SlugField()`... So that was for me the final solution...

Comment: add the complete error traceback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you call `super()` method, you should not pass `self` there as a parameter. So instead of your current code:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    super(PostAdmin, self).save_model(self, request, obj, form)
```

you should call the `super()` without `self` as a parameter, and add the missing `change` on the end:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    super(PostAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Comment: Well, yes, that was silly of me. However my code still hasn't the functionality I want. Now there isn't any error, but admin form still doesn't allow me to save. I even commented `prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}` if that was the reason but I get a prompt to `Enter a valid “slug”...` before the execution of `obj.slug = slugify(obj.title, allow_unicode=True)`. So it seems that there is another method I should override, but I don't know which.

Comment: yeah that's how it always is - there's always yet-another issue during the development. However piggybacking these problems into irrelevant questions via comments won't really fly, so I'd suggest you to open this as a new question.